# UPDATED -> error invalid address | Switched from submit to button but now function is not working?

Tags: javascript

I am getting an invalid address error 
after changing handler to "click" from "submit"
console.log is showing the address being fetched correctly
but I cannot pass it on to the function correctly I think

```
function ready() {
  document.getElementById("bet").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fromAddress1 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress1").value;

    var fromAddress2 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress2").value;

    var betAmount = document.querySelector("#bet #betAmount").value;

    var contract = web3.eth.contract(OraclizeContract.abi).at(OraclizeContract.address);

    console.log(contract)

    OraclizeContract.deployed().then(function (instance, fromAddressX) {

      console.log("Initializing");
      instance.deposit({
        from: fromAddressX,
        gas: 3000000,
        value: web3.toWei(betAmount, 'ether')
      })
        .then(function (v) {
          console.log(v);
          console.log("Function Executed");
        });
    }).then(function () {
      console.log("Testing");
    }).catch(function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    });

    console.log(fromAddress2);

    document.getElementById("player2").addEventListener("click", function (e, fromAddress2) {

    });
    document.getElementById("player1").addEventListener("click", function (e, fromAddress1) {

    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to add a listener to your button, say the click event for example.

Comment: You can’t expect the submit event to fire, if you are not actually submitting the form any more - which you aren’t, because you explicitly made your button _not_ be a submit button any more. _“When i used submit it was constantly refreshing”_ - that’s because you did not prevent the _default_ action of the submit in your event handler, which is submitting the form to the server, so the browser “loads a new page.”

Comment: you mean onClick? but then it says the name is undefined whereas i have a single function in which all these button code exist

Comment: Use ``addEventListener("click", ...`` instead of ``submit``.

Comment: It's poor form to completely alter a question - this isn't a whiteboard.  In the future consider asking a new question regarding changes with a link back to the original question.